# Как происходит отслеживание платной версии gitlab на локальном компьютере?

Tags: gitlab

Есть компания. И хочет использовать все фичи *Gitlab* по максимуму. На странице гитлаба написаны цены https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/  ($99 per user  per month ). Как я понимаю, это если гитлаб развернут в интернете. А если он используется в компании, то как они отслеживают этот момент?

Можно ли вообще купить гитлаб для локального использования? Или всегда адрес должен быть доступен из вне, тем самым отслеживая лецензию гитлаба?

Comment: Вопрос сводится к тому, можно ли его крякнуть и юзать бесплатно?) Можно :)

Comment: нет. вопрос сводится к тому, как это покупать и использовать локально, если, например внешка закрыта. Как это отслеживается, если например, доступ из вне нет. Непонятно. Просто перед покупкой надо понять, платную можно развернуть локально или только для глобального использования. Не ясно

Comment: Зачем отслеживать? Функционал же у версий разный

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не разный, а каждая более оплачиваемая версия добавляет еще какой-то функционал над предыдущей

Comment: Это и называется разный. Если вам не нужен функционал дорогой версии, до зачем ее покупать? А если нужен, то в дешевой вы его не найдете

Comment: @AntonShchyrov спасибо кэп)) А по вопросу будет что-то добавить?))

Comment: Так вы так и не ответили на мой вопрос `Зачем отслеживать? Функционал же у версий разный`. Что нужно отслеживать? Что вы не украли где-то платную версию?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да. Если бы это была разовая покупка - было бы понятно, что заплатил - они дали исходник и делай что хочешь. Но как они понимают, что например у нас бронза и что им надо платить 4$ с человека каждый месяц? Им как-то нужно же это знать? По каким сведениям и данным?

Comment: Вы сами покупаете какую-то версию. И пока платите, пока у вас есть поддержка

Comment: @AntonShchyrov что значит есть поддержка? давайте еще раз на пальцах. Вот я покупаю бронзу на 1-го человека и устанавливаю домой. Без связи с интернетом. Исходник у меня будет, так? Интернета не будет. Вопрос: что мне мешает использовать это на 100 человек? И как они отрубят поддержку, если исходник у меня уже будет? Или должна быть постоянная связь с интернетом, чтобы они по какому-то условному токену знали, что работает столько-то человек и нужна оплата? А без этого токена опять же - что случится если я уже оплатил и исходник у меня есть?

Comment: 1) Вы не получаете обновлений, 2) Вы не можете обратиться в саппорт с вопросом, 3) Врядли вы сможете в базу добавить более одного пользователя

Comment: @AntonShchyrov 1) Плевать 2) плевать 3) опять же - на каком уровне это ограничение стоИт? На уровня выдачи исходника? А если в процессе месяца  мне надо еще одного человека добавить? А двух? А каждый день по-одному? Штат расширяется ежедневно к примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос задан странно, читается именно, что нужен кряк.

Купить полнофункциональный GitLab для локального использования можно.

1. Необходимо сделать апгрейд с Community Edition на Enterprise Edition. Все платные функции будут заблокированы.
2. Купить лицензии.
3. В новой админской панели ввести файл лицензий, полученный по почте.

Лицензии имеют ограничение по времени, после истечения платные функции опять будут заблокированы. Также в панели появляется информация о следующем  рекомендуемом количестве лицезий. У нас случая превышения лицензий не было, что будет не скажу.